# Output shape of Keras model & Caffe model is different for same model architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, caffe

In Keras, output shape of an image changes by 1 after applying `Convolution2D` Layer but works when we apply same model with the Caffe. I was reproducing the results of an [IS&T 2017](https://www.ingentaconnect.com/contentone/ist/ei/2017/00002017/00000007/art00011#) Paper. In that paper they are using Caffe with the similar model.

[image: Model Summary]

My Model Summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 61, 61, 32)        1568      
_________________________________________________________________
**max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 30, 30, 32)        0**         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 48)        38448     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 13, 13, 48)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 9, 9, 64)          76864     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 4, 4, 64)          0         

---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This Results in this Error

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 4 for 'conv2d_4/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,4,4,64], [5,5,64,128].
```

All the dimensions and patch size is taken same.

Comment: Pass `padding='same'` argument to the `MaxPooling2D` layer.

Comment: complement @today 's solution, **valid:** `out_height = ceil(float(in_height - filter_height + 1) / float(strides[1]))`; **same:** `out_height = ceil(float(in_height) / float(strides[1]))` [tensorflow's method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Convolution)

Comment: @today Thank you it worked